# Building Filtering sidebar and searching box

Tags: javascript, php

I want to build filtering sidebar and search box . My problem is, I can't make it run searching box and filtering items together at the same time. I hope any of u can help me?
I think,the main problem is in my script "var s" php parameter where I'm getting cities from 
Let's see what I've done so for,

Here's my script;

```
<script>

 $(function(){
 $('.item_filter').change(function(){   
 var p   = multiple_values('p');
 var s   ='<?php echo $_POST["search"]; ?>';

 var url ="product.php?product=<?php echo 
 htmlentities($_GET['product']) ?>&s="+s+"&b="+b+"&p="+p;
 window.location=url;
 });

 });


 function multiple_values(inputclass){
 var val = new Array();
 $("."+inputclass+":checked").each(function() {
 val.push($(this).val());
 });
 return val.join('-');
  }

</script>


Search Box

 <form class="search" name="search" method="POST" 
 action="product.php?product=<?php echo 
 ''.htmlentities($_GET['product']).''; ?>" >

    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input  id="small_search"  
   name="searchTerm" class="item_filter s" <?php { echo "checked"; } ?> 
   list="local"  /></a>

        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $local = ($row['local']); ?>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank"><input type="submit"  
         id="small_search_btn"  value="Search"></a >
            <datalist id="local">
            <option value="<?php echo ''.htmlentities($row['local']).'';  ? 
          >"></option>

        <?php } ?>
    </form >


   **Filtering **

   <div class="list-group" style="font-size:14px;">
   <h4 style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; color:black;"> 
   </h4>

   <?php 

    some sql statement..
     ?>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item" 
    id="left_filtering" >  
    <label >
    <input type="checkbox" class="item_filter b" value="<?php echo 
    htmlentities($row['brand']); ?>" <?php if(in_array($row['brand'],$b 
   {echo "checked"; } ?> >&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo ucfirst($row['brand']); 
   ?></a>

   </label>
   <?php } ?>  

 </div>
```